Automatically restore screen settings in Gnome (Wayland)
Previously I have been using autorandr to save and automatically restore screen layouts depending on currently connected monitors. Since it is not working I'm looking for a similar tool that supports Gnome.
It should be able to store different screen layouts and automatically change them when monitor (dis)connected.
I have tried alternatives like kanshi but they all seems to require wlroots.
If there are no such tool available, maybe there are some CLI for Gnome to change screen layouts?
